# Get data at the ViewModel class level

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a class defined for my View Model that contains a list and I want to populate that list when my model is created.

For example this works but I feel like I am doing it incorrectly:

```
public class Item
{
     public string ItemNum {get; set;}

     public List<Manufacturers> Manufacturers
     {
          get
          {
              ApplicationContext() _context = new ApplicationContext();
              return _context.Manufacturers.Where(i => i.Item == this.ItemNum).ToList();
          }
     }
}
```

Basically when the Item class gets created I want to go out and populate the associated list to display and work with the information.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you really need to re-query the database every time this is requested?  Will it be changing that often and need to be up to date?  Or should you just query the database *once* when an instance of this object is created and store the results in the object itself?

Comment: @David any examples of what that would look like?  Once would be enough but I cannot think of how I would do it without looping through a foreach statement when I call generate the object.

Answer (score 0):

may be a `constructor` with default `parameter` would fit the bill

```
 public class Item
 {
    //other properties
    public string ItemNum {get; set;}
    private List<Manufacturers> _Manufacturers
    private ApplicationContext() _context;
    public Item (string ItemNum = "some default text"){
       _context = new ApplicationContext();
       _Manufacturers = _context.Manufacturers.Where(i => i.Item == 
       this.ItemNum).ToList();
    }
    public List<Manufacturers> Manufacturers
    {
      get
      {
       return _Manufacturers;
      }
    }
 }
```